# Syntax error when passing function with arguments to a function (python)

Tags: python, syntax-error

Learning decorators and I wanted to pass a function with arguments to a decorator function like shown below but I always get a syntax error. Please help!

```
def decorator(func(*args)):
    def wrapper():
        print('up')
        func(*args)
        print('down')
    return wrapper

@decorator
def func(n):
    print(n)

func('middle')
```

Output:

```
File "<ipython-input-21-c2d727543f8e>", line 1
    def decorator(func(*args)):
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You aren't passing anything, that's your function signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. To define a correct decorator and wrapper function, see what follows:

```
def decorator(func):       # assign the function you want to pass
    def wrapper(*args):    # assign the parameters you want to use for the function
        print('up')
        func(*args)
        print('down')
    return wrapper

@decorator
def func(n):               # The function you want to decorate
    print(n)

func('middle')
```

Output:

```
up
middle
down
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a few changes: arguments for a function you need to provide as *args inside wrapper. And and another thing - remove *args from decorator(func(*args)).

```
def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        print('up')
        func(*args)
        print('down')
    return wrapper

@decorator
def func(n):
    print(n)

func('middle')
```